# manually call onSharedPreferenceChange()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my wallpaper preference activity ,among checkbox preference and list preference, there is an intent to launch a image picker for the background. When the image is picked, the onSharedPreference didn't fire, I found out that only the image picker intent won't trigger the sharedpreference change. So how can I manually trigger it?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

        return;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap;

    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:

            try {

                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFileTemp);
                copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                startCropImage();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("xxx", "Error while creating temp file", e);
            }

            break;

        case REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE:

            String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);
            if (path == null) {

                return;
            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileTemp.getPath());
            imagePreference.setSummary(path);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("imageDb", path);
            editor.commit();
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out by myself. The onSharedPreferenceChange is triggered only if the input data is different from the previous one. The code in question does fire the onSharedPreferenceChange when it first inputs the path of the saved image in the preference. But it no longer fire the second time because the path of the saved image is always the same.

```
Boolean picker = prefs.getBoolean("picker", false);
editor.putBoolean("picker", !picker);
```

The above code input a different boolean value everytime an image is cropped.